# Why everything is disconnected in my Tensorboard graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorboard

I have implemented a CNN for detecting human activity using accelrometer data, my model is working really fine but when i visualize my grapgh on tensorboard, everythin seems to be diconnected. Right now i am not using `Namescopes` but even without it grpagh should make some sense right?

[image: Tensorboard Graph]

**EDIT**  After implementing answer given by @user1735003 , this is the output. What i still don't understand is why i'm getting all the nodes at left

[image]

What i have implemented is: i have two convolution layer and two max-pooling layers and on top of that i have two hidden layers with **1024** and **512** neurons.

so Here is my code:

```
#Weights
def init_weights(shape):
    init_random_dist = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(init_random_dist)


#Bias
def init_bias(shape):
    init_bias = tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(init_bias)

def conv1d(x,weights):
    #x is input accelration data and W is corresponding weight
    return tf.nn.conv1d(value=x,filters = weights,stride=1,padding='VALID')

def convolution_layer(input_x,shape):
   w1 = init_weights(shape)
   b = init_bias([shape[2]])
   return tf.nn.relu(conv1d(input_x,weights=w1)+b)


def normal_full_layer(input_layer,size):
    input_size = int(input_layer.get_shape()[1])
    W = init_weights([input_size, size])
    b = init_bias([size])
    return tf.matmul(input_layer, W) +b


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None ,window_size,3]) #input tensor with 3 input channels
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,6]) #Labels

con_layer_1 = convolution_layer(x,shape=[4,3,32])#filter  of shape [filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]

max_pool_1=tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=con_layer_1,pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='Valid')

con_layer_2 = convolution_layer(max_pool_1,shape=[4,32,64])

max_pool_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=con_layer_2,pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='Valid')

flat = tf.reshape(max_pool_2,[-1,max_pool_2.get_shape()[1]*max_pool_2.get_shape()[2]])

fully_conected = tf.nn.relu(normal_full_layer(flat,1024))


second_hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(normal_full_layer(fully_conected,512))
hold_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
full_one_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(second_hidden_layer,keep_prob=hold_prob)


y_pred = normal_full_layer(full_one_dropout,6)
pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(y_pred)


cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=y_pred))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()




with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init)
filename="./summary_log11/run"
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(filename, graph_def=sess.graph_def)

for i in range(5000):
    batch_x,batch_y = next_batch(100,X_train,y_train)
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, hold_prob: 0.5})

    # PRINT OUT A MESSAGE EVERY 100 STEPS
    if i%100 == 0:

        print('Currently on step {}'.format(i))
        print('Accuracy is:')
        # Test the Train Model
        matches = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1),tf.argmax(y,1))

        acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches,tf.float32))

        print(sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:X_test,y:y_test,hold_prob:1.0}))
        print('\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try organizing your nodes into scopes. That will help Tensorboard to figure out your graph hierarchy. For example,

```
with tf.variable_scope('input'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None ,window_size,3]) #input tensor with 3 input channels
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,6]) #Labels

with tf.variable_scope('net'):

    con_layer_1 = convolution_layer(x,shape=[4,3,32])#filter  of shape [filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]

    max_pool_1=tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=con_layer_1,pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='Valid')

    con_layer_2 = convolution_layer(max_pool_1,shape=[4,32,64])

    max_pool_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=con_layer_2,pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='Valid')

    flat = tf.reshape(max_pool_2,[-1,max_pool_2.get_shape()[1]*max_pool_2.get_shape()[2]])

    fully_conected = tf.nn.relu(normal_full_layer(flat,1024))


    second_hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(normal_full_layer(fully_conected,512))
    hold_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    full_one_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(second_hidden_layer,keep_prob=hold_prob)


    y_pred = normal_full_layer(full_one_dropout,6)
    pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(y_pred)

with tf.variable_scope('loss'):

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=y_pred))

with tf.variable_scope('optimizer'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Comment: Thanks.I implemented the solution, but i am still unable to understand all the nodes at left

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't explicitly name your tf operations it was done automatically by tensorflow, e.g. ReLu operators were named `ReLu_1`, `ReLu_2`, ... . According to [tensorboard documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz#name_scoping_and_nodes):

> One last structural simplification is series collapsing. Sequential motifs--that is, **nodes whose names differ by a number at the end and have isomorphic structures--are collapsed into a single stack of nodes**, as shown below. For networks with long sequences, this greatly simplifies the view.

As you can see at the right side of your graph, all `add_[0-7]`, `MatMul_[0-5]` and `Relu_[0-5]` nodes were grouped together because they have similar names, this doesn't mean that nodes are disconnected in your graph, it's just the tensorboard's node grouping policy.

If you want to avoid this then give your operations the names that are more different than just by a number at the end. Or use [tf.name_scope()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope) as you mentioned, e.g.:

```
with tf.name_scope("conv1"):
  con_layer_1 = convolution_layer(x,shape=[4,3,32])
  max_pool_1=tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=con_layer_1,pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='Valid')

with tf.name_scope("conv2"):
  con_layer_2 = convolution_layer(max_pool_1,shape=[4,32,64])
  max_pool_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=con_layer_2,pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='Valid')

# etc.
```